# How to perform a git rebase of local commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

A common scenario is to perform an interactive rebase of the local git commits before pushing to a repository. One way of doing this is to find the number of local commits and run the command (in this example 3 local commits)

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Is there a way of saving the need to find out the number of local commits beforehand, and directly run a command that means `git rebase -i 'commits not yet pushed'`.

**Edit**: Let me elaborate by giving a specific scenario. I perform three commits:

```
Commit change A
Commit change B
Commit change C
```

At this point I realize that the changes in C belong with the changes in A, so I want to rebase to give me what I want:

```
Commit containing A + C
Commit containing B
```

At this point, there has been no push. Seeing as I cannot remember how many changes the change C was, I do a

```
git log @{u}..
```

and determine that I have three changes. So now I want to do a

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Or, as @cosimo93 points out, I can simply do

```
git rebase -i
```

Comment: Let's say you have the local commits and you have not pushed them. You can rebase them with same command. If there are merge commit messages and you want to include them in the rebase then you need to use the flag `-p` to preserve merge commits in your interactive rebase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just try:

```
git rebase -i
```

Comment: I have the same doubts about OP's intentions and needs, but this probably should have been a comment, since it doesn't technically answer the question. Just sayin'

Comment: I hereby bow to the whimsical goddess of Improbability ;-) Upvoted for concision.